# How to get delay between each songs in AVQueuePlayer on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I've created songQueue and added set of songs to it. I've created like each songs in the queue plays one after another but I want to add certain gap (myModel.delay) between each songs.

I used below code to create the queue of songs and play it using this function

```
func play(){


 songQueue = {
              let sound1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.myModel.song[0].sURL, withExtension:nil)!
               let sound2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.myModel.song[1].sURL, withExtension:nil)!
              let sound3 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.myModel.song[2].sURL, withExtension:nil)!

              let s1 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound1)
              let s2 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound2)
              let s3 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound3)
              let queue = AVQueuePlayer(items: [s1, s2, s3])
              return queue
           }()
               self.songQueue.play()
        }
```

This is the button I use to play the songs

```
                            Button(action: myModel.play
                        ){
                            Image(systemName: "pause.fill")
                               .resizable()
                                .padding(.all, 30)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                
                        }.onAppear(perform: {
                            myModel.play()
                            })
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @nickcarraway - Noted your bounty comment. Both answers are already in Swift. What are you looking for?

Comment: If I could unbounty it, I would. I thought the answer was incomplete until I tried it out. It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Very old technic but effective from Objective-C.

Add an `observer` to `EndPlay notification`. Then pause the play for some second(delay) while receiving notification and then play the player using GCD dispatch with delay.

*Observer:*

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerEndedPlaying), name: Notification.Name("AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: nil)
```

*Notification Call back*

```
@objc func playerEndedPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.songQueue?.pause()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + DELAY_IN_SECONDS) {[weak self] in
        self?.songQueue?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please guide me, like how to apply this for my solution? cz I'm new to swift

Comment: Are you using SwitfUI or Swift?

Comment: I'm using swiftUI

Comment: In Body getter, define OnAppear for root view, Inside OnAppear function, register the Observer. Then define the call back function.

Comment: nope, that didn't work :( I want delay between each songs in the queue

Comment: When you receive notification, you have to pause/Stop the player. Dispatch queue will give call back after the delay time(Defined your time), in this call back, then resume to play.

Comment: I've edited my code by adding button and .onAppear. can you please check if you could help me out

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter if you use SwiftUI or UIKit. `AVQueuePlayer` is in `AVFoundation`.
@mani is right you need to observe `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` but the observer needs to be added to `currentItem` in queue and not `object: nil` see [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime)

in `Swift`:

1. prevent queue player to play queued items automatically `player.actionAtItemEnd = .paused`
2. listen to `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: player.currentItem,
    queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.advance()
    })
```

3. start next song with delay

```
 func advance() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { [weak self] in
    self?.player.advanceToNextItem()
    self?.player.play()
 }
```

Note: you need to add notification observer to `currentItem` in player not the player itself. Meaning: each time you play a new item you need to call `notificationCenter.removeObserver(..)` and `notificationCenter.addObserver(..)` to observe the current item

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve it very simply, is to use a "Pause" song which you play between the songs. Simply record a soundclip with muted micro and the duration of the pause you want to have.

Insert it into the table like that:

```
          let pause = AVPlayerItem(url: pause)

          let s1 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound1)
          let s2 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound2)
          let s3 = AVPlayerItem(url: sound3)

          let queue = AVQueuePlayer(items: [s1, pause, s2, pause, s3])
          return queue
```

not the most elegant way.. but should work

Comment: thank you for the reply. but is there any other way you know to inserting delay using numbers?

Comment: What do you you mean by number? Do you want to change the pause over time or will it be fixed for all times? If you want to have this pause length changeable, the only way I know is the way Mani has described and it should work perfectly. If you simply have a fixed length, then trimm the sound file of the "pause" according to that requested length.

Comment: This only works as expected when the playback speed (AVPlayer.rate) is 1.0

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
  var player: AVQueuePlayer
  var delayBetweenSongs: TimeInterval // the delay between each song in seconds

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    
    _ = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { time in
        guard self.player.timeControlStatus == .playing else { return }
        
        if let currentItem = self.player.currentItem {
            let remainingTime = currentItem.duration - currentItem.currentTime()
            
            if remainingTime <= CMTime(seconds: self.delayBetweenSongs, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)) {
                // delay has elapsed, skip to next item
                self.player.advanceToNextItem()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use PlayerView

```
let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: [AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "song1.mp3")!), AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "song2.mp4")!)])
let playerView = PlayerView(player: player, delayBetweenSongs: 5.0)
```